# In RPL, How do I block some node at link layer itself so that further layer do not process the data from that node?

Tags: contiki, cooja

I want to block malicious node at data-link layer itself so that the further layers do not have to process data from that node. Is there any way to block all communications from that node.
Note: I have IP address of identified malicious node, e.g. fe80::c30c:0:0:13

Ideas are welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean by data link layer in the context of Contiki? There are radio, RDC, MAC and network layers in the OS.

Comment: By data link layer I mean MAC layer.